# onLocationChanged has not been called

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

i've been trying to create a map-related android app, but i realized that the onLocationChanged of my app had not been called, therefore the map always stay at the default area (US).

my code:

```
public class MapMainActivity extends MapActivity 
implements OnClickListener, LocationListener {

MapView mapView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_main);

    //reference
    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    this.findViewById(R.id.btn_satellite).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.findViewById(R.id.btn_street).setOnClickListener(this);

}//onCreate

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS tracking started",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 // Start location updates; 5s/5m
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(
        Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        5000, 0, this);

    Criteria crit = new Criteria();
    crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
    Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

}//onResume

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS tracking stopped", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locManager.removeUpdates(this);
}//onPause

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v == findViewById(R.id.btn_street))
    {
        mapView.setSatellite(false);
    }//street view

    else if (v == findViewById(R.id.btn_satellite))
    {
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
    }
}//onClick

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}//isRouteDisplayed

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lon = location.getLongitude();

    TextView txtLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_lat);
    txtLat.setText(String.format("%.6f", lat));
    TextView txtLon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_lon);
    txtLon.setText(String.format("%.6f", lon));

    MapView map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    map.getController().animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6),//1000000), 
        (int)(lon*1E6)));
}//onLocationChanged

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS disabled", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}//onProviderDisabled

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS enabled", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}//onProviderEnabled

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}//onStatusChanged


}//class
```

the whole of my log cat when i run the app through my device (16/12/2011)

```
D/InputTransport(5357): Input channel constructed: name='40baf680 Toast (client)', ashmemFd=54, receivePipeFd=57, sendPipeFd=58

I/MapActivity(5357): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED

E/MapActivity(5357): Couldn't get connection factory client

I/ViewRoot(5357): !@FINISH DRAWING : sg.edu.tp/sg.edu.tp.SIP_TestMapActivity

I/ViewRoot(5357): !@finishDrawing is completed : sg.edu.tp/sg.edu.tp.SIP_TestMapActivity

I/ViewRoot(5357): !@FINISH DRAWING : Toast

I/ViewRoot(5357): !@finishDrawing is completed : Toast

D/InputTransport(5357): Input channel destroyed: name='40baf680 Toast (client)', ashmemFd=54, receivePipeFd=57, sendPipeFd=58
```

manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sg.edu.tp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SIP_MLT_TestActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".SIP_TestMapActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SIP_TestDraw1Activity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SIP_TestDraw2Activity"></activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: how did you changed the location??

Comment: er... i dont really get what you mean. but, since i'm not in state, when i run the app it shouldn't display the states map.

Comment: nope, i run it through my device (samsung galaxy R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing that while moving about or while sitting tethered to your dev machine with USB and watching logcat?

If sitting at dev machine, I suspect you're not able to move the 5 meters required to trigger a location change event as you requested in your call to requestLocationUpdates

From [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) docs: .

> If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcast if
>   the device moves by minDistance meters.

try reducing the min distance param in that call to zero and see what happens.

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000, 0, this);
```

You probably dont want to leave that at zero for anything other than testing.

If that doesnt help you might try to see that your GPS is working at all by doing something like this in your onResume, after you ask for locationUpdates:

```
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(crit, true);
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

and see if you are getting good location info.

Comment: yes, i test it with the usb plugged to my com. nothing happens when i changed from 5 to 0. i tested the app with a log inserted at the onLocationChanged method, and when i run the app, the log does not appear. so my guess is it does not even enter that method.

Comment: hi, nothing seems to happen. i've update the code and my LogCat above. please help. thanks =)

Comment: try doing some logging at the end of onResume and see what loc contains then to make sure youre getting something back from the location provider.

Comment: Also are you certain your manifest contains the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>?

Comment: after i added a Log.d("location",String.valueof(loc)) in the onResume, after the criteria, the return is a null

Comment: Have your tried starting your activity, hitting home and then starting your activity again? It's possible the location provider hasnt spooled up between the requestLocationUpdate and the logging of getLastKnown but if you try running and quitting a few times it should give something eventually. If you are convinced youre always getting nothing then it seems the device GPS receiver might not be turned on. Check that and double check your permission for FINE_LOCATION in manifest, please.

Comment: it turns out that when i tested the app walking in real(not attaching to usb etc), it returns the longitude and latitude. so i guess its working... thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Location stuiff is tricky.  On one side, you need recent location fast, with best precision possible on  the other side you do no like to  drain battery fast.  There are also differences between API levels.  See this manual for detailed explanation:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

As for your original question - requersting location updates ist just a recomendation  to location manager to send you those updates after something changes. It's no obliged to do 
so.   Your GPS system may be not fine enough (and is certainly not)  to detect snall location changes while leashed on USB cable.  For testing purposes, you could create mock provider
and manipulate it with outher application.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addTestProvider%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: hi, could you let me know how and where should i put the code ? thks